# FInd CDF of $X$ if: $P(X<1)=P(X>2)=0, P(X=1)=P(X=2),P(a<X<b)=\tfrac{b^3-a^3}{14}$ for $1\leq a<b\leq2$

Tags: probability, solution-verification, cumulative-distribution-functions

> **The Problem:** Suppose we know the following about a random variable $X$:
>   $$P(X<1)=P(X>2)=0,$$
>   $$P(X=1)=P(X=2),$$
>   $$P(a<X<b)=\frac{b^3-a^3}{14}\quad\text{for }1\leq a<b\leq2.$$
>   Find the cumulative distribution function of $X$.

**My Thoughts:** By the given conditions and additivity, we have
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
1&=P(X=1)+P(1<X<2)+P(X=2)\\
&=P(X=1)+\frac{1}{2}+P(X=2),
\end{split}\end{equation}
so that $P(X=1)=P(X=2)=\dfrac{1}{4}.$ Now, if $P(X=t)=\delta>0$ for some $t\in(1,2)$, then
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
P(1<X<2)
&=P(1<X<t)+P(X=t)+P(t<X<2)\\
&=\frac{t^3-1}{14}+\delta+\frac{2^3-t^3}{14}\\
&=P(1<X<2)+\delta,
\end{split}\end{equation}
so that $P(X=t)=0$ for all $1<t<2$, whence $P(1<X\leq t)=P(1<X<t)$ for $1<t<2$. Therefore,
$$F_X(t)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if }t<1\\
\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{t^3-1}{14}&\text{if }1\leq t<2\\
1&\text{if }t\geq2.
\end{cases}$$

---

Do you agree with my execution? Any feedback is much appreciated and welcomed. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Looks perfect to me.

Comment: @heropup and OP how come $P(1<X<2)=\frac{1}{2}$  ?